# Diablo 3 new authentication key

Tags: diablo-iii

I purchased Diablo 3 without checking the requirements (I know, I'm dumb).  I got it working, but it's insanely slow and barely playable.  I give up and I won't be playing it. So I want to give my copy to a friend, but I assume they won't be able to install it without the authentication key, correct?  Is there any way I can get a new key so my friend can install it on his machine?

Comment: A key is not required to install Diablo 3. You can play any installation of Diablo 3 by logging in with a valid Battle.net account (valid being any account which has a Diablo 3 license in good standing).

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried asking customer service?  They don't have to do anything about it, but if you explain it doesn't play well for you, and you'd like to make your friend incredibly happy, they may do it for you anyway.

[They do returns if you just don't like the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15MJj.jpg) so maybe they'll do a transfer if it's unplayable.

Comment: Worst case, you could probably do a return (surely unplayable justifies not liking it), and re-buy it for your friend. I can't see why they wouldn't just do the transfer if it's possible for them to do.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way for you to transfer your copy. It is permanently tied to your Battle.net account.

Answer (score 1):

No. Battle.net registration keys are single-use and are bound to your Battle.net account after you enter the key. If the registration key has been tied to your Battle.net account (if you were able to play the game, it was), it is not possible to un-assign or transfer that registration key. The only way for your friend to get their own registration key would be to buy a new copy of the game.

Comment: Or give them you battle.net account (you do create a new account for each game, for this purpose, right?)